# Load multiple json files and display it to the html using ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to grab three different json files that contain objects and load them into a single page using the jquery get method. I need to grab the objects and display all three to the page using jquery. I am having trouble loading and displaying all three... any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $.get("objectone.json", function(data){
        $('#mydiv').html((JSON.stringify(data)));
    });
    $.get("objectwo.json", function(data){
        $('#mydiv').html((JSON.stringify(data)));
    });
    $.get("objectthree.json", function(data){
        $('#mydiv').html((JSON.stringify(data)));
    });
  });
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<button type="button" name="button">Click Me</button>

<div id="mydiv">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.html()` method use `.append()` of JQuery.

> Since you are using `.html()` it will replace the previous content
>   with the new content whenever you call it, whereas with `.append()` it
>   will add to the exisiting content.

Read More [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "https://rawgit.com/typicode/json-server/master/routes.json";
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      $('#mydiv').append((JSON.stringify(data)));
    });
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      $('#mydiv').append((JSON.stringify(data)));
    });
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      $('#mydiv').append((JSON.stringify(data)));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" name="button">Click Me</button>

<div id="mydiv">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The .html method replaces all of the contents of the selected element with the html contents you provide.
By using it three times on the same element you replace *all* of the contents three times.

Replace .html with .append, which adds the new data to the end of the contents of the selected element.

Comment: Gotcha! Is there anyway to stop the function from running when all three objects appear on the page? Because everytime I click the button to run the function another set of the same objects appear. Anyway to keep that from happening?

Comment: @MujoM You can either remove the button or stop it from working. 
To remove it: $("button").remove(); and to stop it from working: $("button").unbind('click'). Just add one of the above at the end of the "click" callback (one line before the last one)

Comment: @MujoM you can also add a class to the element to indicate that it has been filled. At the end of the callback function: $("mydiv").addClass('filled'); and in the beginning ad an "if" with if (!$("mydiv").hasClass('filled') { the rest of the code here }

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help!